# A short story about finding a planet where there is a great hall full of statues of deities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, comics

There are a group of humans that find—on a planet—some kind of great hall (possibly in ruins), full of strange statues that seem to resemble various forms of the messiah, both human and alien like. Something happens, they open fire, and a darkness starts consuming everything.

I came across this one mid-'80s, but it might be quite a bit older, and a short film adaptation might also exist.

Any idea what this is?

Comment: Off to a good start, but we could use some more details, such as when you may have read it/ when it may have been published. If you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: Did you intend to tag this with [comics]? It was there originally but you refer to it as a short story so I edited it out. Just making sure.

Comment: well I'm not sure but it might have been a "comic" illustration too ...

Comment: The scene with the statues reminds me a bit Jack McDevitt's Academy series and in particular the "Engines of God". Could it be that ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Engines_of_God )?

Comment: My stars! It's full of gods.

Comment: Sounds familiar to a short story I remember about a hall of statues. One gets broken and some trapped evil is released. I can't remember the title, though.

Comment: I remember this as a black and white magazine sized short comic story. Illustration by Neal Adams, I think. Ship lands, crew discover a remple and hall of statues as described (including Jesus). Horrible, squirmy monster at the end, which they kill. Only to discover that was God, and now the darkness of the end of the universe flows toward them. I thought it may be in the UWOSF series by Marvel but it appears not.

Comment: Well, @Martin you were spot on! Seems I was right from the beginning to put it under the "comics" tag to. It is indeed from "Marvel Preview Vol 1 #1" 1975, title:Good Lord!
[link](http://atocom.blogspot.gr/2012/05/reading-room-good-lord.html)

Thank you all.

Comment: @JohnT.Semer I think the powers that be on this site like you to confirm you’ve found an answer. Not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment by Martin May (but never followed up on), this is the comic story "[Good Lord!](http://atocom.blogspot.com/2012/05/reading-room-good-lord.html)" with script by [Marv Wolfman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marv_Wolfman) and art by [Dave Cockrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Cockrum).  [The story is an homage](http://diversionsofthegroovykind.blogspot.com/2011/08/black-and-white-wednesday-good-lord-by.html) to earlier pulp-style science fiction and adventure stories.  It was first published in *[Marvel Preview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Preview)* no. 1 (1975) and reprinted in no. 20 (in 1980)

On the last two pages of the story, you can see the statues of messianic figures from all around the galaxy, including Earth.  Then there is shooting, which precipitates the death of God, and blackness begins to devour everything.

[image: Page 71][image: Page 72]

Answer (score 2):

It appears this is not the answer, but I wanted to leave this here for future reference when people search the site:

*[To Die in Italbar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1393081.To_Die_in_Italbar)* (1973) by Roger Zelazny contains a similar scene.  The last third of the novel was completely rewritten a few years later after Zelazny's first draft was rejected; with the revisions, he made the book a sequel to his 1969 novel *[Isle of the Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1124895.Isle_of_the_Dead)*.

As eventually published, both novels involve the gods of the alien Pei'ans pantheon.  Most of the Pei'an's gods have Pei'an-like bodies, but some have the form of other alien races that the Pei'an spacefarer's have met; for example, Shimbo of Darktree, Shrugger of Thunders, is a human.  In *To Die in Italbar*, some of the characters find their way into the ruins of a Pei'an temple, with the images of all the gods surrounding them on the walls.  Eventually, a party physical, partly psychic battle takes place between two of the gods, who have incarnated themselves through humans.